# WORKDAY Google Sheet formula in SQL Google Console

Tags: sql, date, workday-api, date-manipulation

I need to find a new date adding to the current one a number, but excluding weekends.
I can do this in Google Sheet with the WORKDAY formula but I need to do it in SQL.

As an example:

Current day: 2023-09-23
set_term = 6

Date I am expecting to obtain: 2023-10-02